# What is the correct tensor shape for batch training?

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, tensor

I've been working on a machine learning system to identify stars based on light values using pytorch.  I use batch training, with five values that serve as inputs.  I am unsure of what size array to convert it to and was hoping someone knew the correct way to format my data.
The code below is what I'm working on, for context.  When run, it cites and issue with the model, which runs until explaining that the two tensors cannot be multiplied.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

# device config
# FIXFIXFIX
#device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
device = torch.device('cpu')

input_size = 5
hidden_size = 4
num_classes = 3
num_epochs = 2
batch_size = 100
learning_rate = 0.001

class SDSS(Dataset):

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize data, download, etc.
        # read with numpy or pandas
        xy = np.loadtxt('SDSS.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32, skiprows=0)
        self.n_samples = xy.shape[0]

        # here the first column is the class label, the rest are the features
        self.x_data = torch.from_numpy(xy[:, 1:]) # size [n_samples, n_features]
        self.y_data = torch.from_numpy(xy[:, [0]]) # size [n_samples, 1]

    # support indexing such that dataset[i] can be used to get i-th sample
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x_data[index], self.y_data[index]

    # we can call len(dataset) to return the size
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n_samples


#I like having this separate, so I remember why I called it when I look back.  Also, if I want to change only this later, I can.
class testSDSS(Dataset):

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize data, download, etc.
        # read with numpy or pandas
        xy = np.loadtxt('SDSS.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32, skiprows=0)
        self.n_samples = xy.shape[0]

        # here the first column is the class label, the rest are the features
        self.x_data = torch.from_numpy(xy[:, 1:]) # size [n_samples, n_features]
        self.y_data = torch.from_numpy(xy[:, [0]]) # size [n_samples, 1]

    # support indexing such that dataset[i] can be used to get i-th sample
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.x_data[index], self.y_data[index]

    # we can call len(dataset) to return the size
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n_samples

#easy to read labels 
dataset = SDSS()
test_dataset = testSDSS()

data_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, num_workers=0)

#Use LeakyReLu to preserve backwards attempts
#softmax is applied in pytorch through cross entropy
class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_classes):
        super(NeuralNet,self).__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.relu = nn.LeakyReLU()
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.l1(x)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.l2(out)
        return out

model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, num_classes)

dataiter = iter(data_loader)
data = next(dataiter)
features, labels = data
print(features, labels)

# loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
opimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

#training loop

n_total_steps = len(dataset)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(data_loader):

        #forward
                    # I believe this shape is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.
        inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,500).to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        #backward
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if (i+1)%100 == 0:
            print(f'epoch {epoch + 1} / {num_epochs}, step {i+1}/{n_total_steps}, loss = {loss.item():.4f}')
```

I have tried altering the tensor shapes, but I don't know what it needs to be so it has been a lot of guessing.

Comment: delete the `inputs.reshape` line, you shouldn't need to reshape the input. It needs to be `[*, input_size]` where `*` is any number. The value of `input_size` must be the same as `n_features` in your dataset. Instead of making it a constant you should just initialize the neural network with the correct input size. something like `model = NeuralNet(dataset.x_data.shape[1], hidden_size, num_classes)`

Comment: This worked - I just had to flatten them.  Thank you for your help!